# Return arguments from function calling with OpenAI API when streaming?

Tags: json, next.js, openai-api

I've made a simple OpenAI API example with function calling. I'm only using function calling to format the response, I'm not calling multiple functions or any external APIs.

When I don't stream the response I can return the function arguments, which is the data that I need.

In my NextJS route handler:

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    const openai = new OpenAI({
      apiKey: process.env["OPENAI_API_KEY"],
    });
    const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      model: "gpt-4",
      // stream: true,
      messages: [
        {
          role: "user",
          content: "Give me 5 questions and answers for a pub quiz",
        },
      ],
      tools: [
        {
          type: "function",
          function: {
            name: "get_questions_and_answers",
            description: "Get questions and answers",
            parameters: simpleJsonSchema,
          },
        },
      ],
      tool_choice: {
        type: "function",
        function: { name: "get_questions_and_answers" },
      },
    });
    return Response.json(
       JSON.parse(
         response.choices[0].message.tool_calls?.[0].function.arguments || "",
       ),
    );
  } catch (serverError) {
    console.error({ serverError });
    throw new Error();
  }
}
```

simpleJsonSchema.json:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "getQuestions": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Question": {"type": "string"},
          "Answer": {"type": "string"}
        },
        "required": ["Question", "Answer"]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["getQuestions"]
}
```

Response from API:

```
{"getQuestions":[{"Question":"What is the capital of Australia?","Answer":"Canberra"},{"Question":"Who wrote 'To Kill a Mockingbird'?","Answer":"Harper Lee"},{"Question":"What is the highest peak in the world?","Answer":"Mount Everest"},{"Question":"Who is known as the 'Father of Computers'?","Answer":"Charles Babbage"},{"Question":"What is the largest ocean in the world?","Answer":"Pacific Ocean"}]}
```

This is fine when developing locally, however when deployed to Vercel the request sometimes times out. I've tried to add streaming as this is the recommended solution:

```
const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
  model: "gpt-4",
  stream: true,
  messages: [
    {
      role: "user",
      content: "Give me 5 questions and answers for a pub quiz",
    },
  ],
  tools: [
    {
      type: "function",
      function: {
        name: "get_questions_and_answers",
        description: "Get questions and answers",
        parameters: simpleJsonSchema,
      },
    },
  ],
  tool_choice: {
    type: "function",
    function: { name: "get_questions_and_answers" },
  },
});

const stream = OpenAIStream(response);
return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
```

However now the response has a lot of unnecessary data. And when I try to JSON.parse on the client I get errors.

Response from API:

```
{"tool_calls":[ {"id": "call_IhxvzkZ5EsmZpHc6tOznTmzb", "type": "function", "function": {"name": "get_questions_and_answers", "arguments": "{\n  \"getQuestions\": [\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Question 1\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Answer 1\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Question 2\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Answer 2\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Question 3\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Answer 3\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Question 4\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Answer 4\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Question 5\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Answer 5\"\n    }\n  ]\n}"}}
```

As far as I can see the docs only cover using `useChat` but I have some particular requirements so I need to handle the fetching and form state myself: https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs/api-reference/use-chat

Why am I getting invalid JSON?

Here is a repository which reproduces the issue: https://github.com/jameschetwood/openai-function-calling

Comment: would you create a reproducible repo?

Comment: @Yilmaz yes https://github.com/jameschetwood/openai-function-calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the response you are getting:

```
{"tool_calls":[ {"id": "call_HRxqlP3yzeHsoN43tMyZjMlr", "type": "function", "function": {"name": "get_questions_and_answers", "arguments": "{\n  \"getQuestions\": [\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"What is the capital city of France?\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Paris\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Who painted the Mona Lisa?\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Leonardo da Vinci\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"What is the largest planet in our solar system?\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Jupiter\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"What is the national flower of England?\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Rose\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Which country is famous for its tulips?\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Netherlands\"\n    }\n  ]\n}"}}
```

I used https://jsoneditoronline.org/ to auto correct the json and it just adds "]}". for some reason openai is not sending correct json response. you have to add it

```
accumulatedText += "]}";
```

then response works:

[image]

this is too specific error. if openai updates its response api, it might send the json data correctly. so a better approach would be parsing in `try/catch`

```
try {
      const parsed = JSON.parse(accumulatedText);
      console.log({ parsed });
    } catch (error) {
      // you should error for each specific case
      accumulatedText += "]}";
      console.log("correct accumulatedText in catch block", accumulatedText);
    }
```

Comment: Good to know about jsoneditoronline.org's auto-repair feature. It would be great if this was available in an NPM package as then the result would be more robust.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

As you already figured out with the help of other StackOverflow members, the problem is that the following JSON is missing `]}` at the end.

```
{"tool_calls":[ {"id": "call_IhxvzkZ5EsmZpHc6tOznTmzb", "type": "function", "function": {"name": "get_questions_and_answers", "arguments": "{\n  \"getQuestions\": [\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Question 1\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Answer 1\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Question 2\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Answer 2\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Question 3\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Answer 3\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Question 4\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Answer 4\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"Question\": \"Question 5\",\n      \"Answer\": \"Answer 5\"\n    }\n  ]\n}"}}
```

#### Solution

Hardcoding `accumulatedText += "]}";` is, of course, not a good solution. As you said, having a package to fix the JSON would be a goal.

Actually, https://jsoneditoronline.org is available as an NPM package. It's called [`jsonrepair`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonrepair).

I forked your GitHub repo and made the following changes to your streaming `page.tsx` file (see the comments in the code below):

```
"use client";
// import JSON5 from "json5";
import { jsonrepair } from "jsonrepair"; // Added

export default function Home() {
  async function callApi() {
    const response = await fetch(`streamed/api/chat2`, {
      method: "POST",
    });
    console.log({ response });

    if (!response.body) throw new Error("no body from response");

    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    let accumulatedText = "";
    while (true) {
      const readValues = await reader.read();
      const { value, done } = readValues;
      if (done) break;
      const text = decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
      accumulatedText += text;
    }
    console.log({ accumulatedText });

    const repairedJSON = jsonrepair(accumulatedText); // Added

    const parsed = JSON.parse(repairedJSON); // Changed
    console.log({ parsed });
  }
  return (
    <main className={"p-10"}>
      <h1 className={"pb-4"}>OpenAI Test - streamed</h1>
      <button
        className={"bg-orange-400 rounded px-4 py-2"}
        onClick={callApi}
        type={"button"}
      >
        Test
      </button>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Doing so, I was able to get a response without an error:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The response that you have mentioned seems to be incorrect as there are no closing tags for the outer object and the array. Try appending "]}" to the response and it should just work fine.

Thank you. Happy to help if there are further questions.